# Search a cell for a string in Excel sheet using openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I have some unnecessary rows in an Excel spreadsheet which I need to remove. The Excel sheet always generates lines at the end of a report I wish to remove using openpyxl. An example cell is `Report Generated By  : NAME`

I have attempted this but am receiving an 'TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable' error. Here is my code:

```
import openpyxl as xl
import os
filename = "1615449726873.xlsx"

wb = xl.load_workbook(filename)
sheet = wb[os.path.splitext(filename)[0]]

for row in range(2, sheet.max_row +1):
    if 'Report Generated By  :' in sheet.cell(row, 1).value:
        sheet.delete_rows(row, 1)

wb.save("testing.xlsx")
```

I have had success in removing cells with == a string (see below), however, the sheet also has cells with have dynamic content so I need CONTAINS rather than is EQUAL TO to work as well. This code works:

```
for row in range(2, sheet.max_row +1):
    if sheet.cell(row, 1).value is == 'Report Generated On:':
        sheet.delete_rows(row, 1)
```

Can someone explain why the second example works but the first does not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that empty cells are returning NoneType. You can get around that my casting the cell value as a string like this

```
for row in range(2, sheet.max_row +1):
    if 'Report Generated By  :' in str(sheet.cell(row, 1).value):
        sheet.delete_rows(row, 1)

wb.save("testing.xlsx")
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you assume all cells have strings for values but they could be numbers, datetimes or None.

Also when deleting rows from the top of the worksheet your counter will become inaccurate, much better to do this from the bottom.

```
for idx in range(sheet.max_row, 0, -1):
    cell = ws.cell(idx, 1)
    if cell.value and "Report Generated By  :" in cell.value:
        sheet.delete_rows(idx)
```